# how to fix a codeblock group width in wordpress edit

Tags: slideshow, screen-layout

I am new developer to wordpress, so please forgive the basic question.

I have a problem with width of a column group.

I have a 2 column column group.  on the left side I have a slide show, and on the right, I have a pair of vertically stacked images.  See below:
[image]

in the edit page, this looks extremely normal.  no problems.

But when I go to preview, the whole thing is pushed extremely right.  When looking at the CSS, the width for the column group exceeds 3 million pixels with right justification.  I've tried this in both regular Wordpress blocks and with Elementor blocks.

WHere can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share the link and also the exact class name that pixel getting change in preview

Comment: Hi Rajneesh.  Thanks!  https://louisianabda.org/landing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display grid/flex have some weird problem when using any kind of slider, I noticed it happening with [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/)

The solution to it is also a bit weird but simple.

All you have to do is add `min-width: 0;` to the parent element of the slider and thats it. (if I remember correctly)

If that didn't help its most likely that the `min-width: 0;` is not in the correct location. Just keep adding it to every above element until it works =].

No idea why that happens but this solution worked for me every time this bug happend.